# I'm having problime with a searech field. The search is not working for a name="" tag

Tags: search, replace, full-text-search

I'm trying to change the field/tag name for a search. But it's not working. I think my name tag is the problem because if I change the name tag field to another name it works for that search name.

```
<div id="top-search" class=" navbar-default navbar listing-search <?php echo   ($dir_searchbar_show=='yes'? '': 'div-hide') ?>" >
<div class=" navbar-collapse text-left" >
 <form class="form-inline advanced-serach" method="POST"  onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="input-field ">  

<div class="form-group top-8" > 
<input type="text" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="cities_served" name="cities_served"   multiple="" accept="cities_served" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('city', 'medical-directory'); ?>"   value="<?php echo trim($cities_served); ?>"/> 
<?php $pos = $main_class->get_unique_cities_served_values('cities_served',$directory_url_2);?> 
</div>

<div class="form-group search top-8" >                              
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  class="btn-new btn-custom-search "><i class="fa fa-  search"></i><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Search', 'medical-directory' ); ?></span>
</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to take the time to correct your title if you expect us to take time to answer. Which language do you use? On a professional QA website, 'not working' is pointless, explains. Please, read [How to ask good questions](https://zacanger.com/blog/posts/using-stackoverflow-effectively/)

Comment: And please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Can't quite tell what you're question is directly referring to, but looking at your tags and taking some context clues, it seems like you are having issues with "find and replace" in your IDE or text editor. If the string of characters you are looking for does not exist in the file, the feature will not find anything.
If you simply search for `name = ""`, it will look for exactly that and nothing more; however, if you search for `name = "`, you'll get a list and every matched result will be highlighted. See the linked photos.

[text find `name=""`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuerT.png)

[text find `name="`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfoTL.png)

[vscode search `name="`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLTuh.png)